# Can we tell meaning of mantras in other languages instead of Sanskrit in Homam,Sandhyavandhanam,etc?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit

Why I am asking this is because ,Sanskrit is a language ,why cant we tell the meaning of mantra in other language in ritiuals like Sandhyavandhanam,homam etc because I think god knows also other languages and also It is easy for us for remembarance and also help others understand our mantras.

Comment: Yes whatever you are saying is correct but on the above mentioned link there is both Yes and No answer to that question soo.

Comment: Look at most upvoted answer. You can't read translated mantras. The power lies in the mantras and the tone of the mantras chanted which will be lost when they are read in other languages. So, they should be chanted as they are.

Comment: For prayer, you can use any language though.